# Approximation results for 3-partition

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, partition-problem

The 3-partition as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) is a strongly NP-complete decision problem. Consider one optimization problem of 3-partition where the $m$ subsets each have at most three elements and a sum of not more than $B$ The goal is to minimize $s(S) - \sum_{k=1}^{m} s(S_k)$, i.e. the total value of leftover elements.

This is obviously strongly NP-complete as well. I am asking if anyone is aware of approximation/inapproximability results (other than the obvious nonexistence of FPTAS). I tried searching, but maybe I am not using the correct keywords.

<s>EDIT: As pointed out in the comment below, there is no constant-factor approximation. Are there any (non-constant) approximation results?</s>

Comment: If the objective is to minimize the total value of leftover elements, then any constant-factor approximation is NP-hard for a trivial reason (distinguishing 0 from nonzero is equivalent to the decision version of 3-partition, which is NP-complete).  Maybe you want to use a different objective function.

Comment: Good point, I arrived at that shortly before your comment, I am still a bit slow at these realizations. I'll modify the question asking for other results.

Comment: In fact, whether it is a _constant_-factor approximation or not is not important.  Even a non-constant-factor approximation implies P=NP; if you want to use your objective function, you cannot hope for a multiplicative approximation at all (unless you prove P=NP at the same time).  One way to work around this is to consider additive approximation, but it seems easier to me to consider multiplicative approximation under a different objective function.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto actually, what prevents the argument you give from working for any approximation as well, like $O(log m)$?

Comment: Nothing.  See my second comment. :)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto again realized that a bit late :-). So the answer turns out to be quite easy. You could turn your comment to an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: One way to "fix" the formulation is to instead maximize the number of "covered" elements. This is the more natural generalization of 2-partition, which is just matching. Then the approximation questions are well founded.

Comment: @SureshVenkat mm.. That sounds reasonable except that I wanted the values to play a role in the cost function.. Can it be fixed in such a way that $s(.)$ is involved?

Comment: Sure. maximize $\sum s(S_k)$

Comment: @SureshVenkat That was the first thing I looked at, but somehow I convinced myself that it has the same problem as minimizing the original objective function.

Comment: Well for the exact answer it is. For approximations it isn't.